# Laravel Homestead Vagrant - Cannot see site - installing problems

Tags: bash, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have been attempting getting this to work now for 4 hours now and I am struggling.

I am trying to get my homestead working. I followed the installation guide here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead

I have a few questions:

1.) When I install homestead by cloning the github repo - I get a `src` folder in that installation and in that `src` folder I have this: `src/stubs/Homestead.yaml`. When I followed the instructions I ran bash init.sh inside of the root of that installation and that created a `/.homestead` folder with 3 files in it a `after.sh` a `aliases` and a `Homestead.yml` file. From my understanding I am to modify the `Homestead.yml` to reflect my enviornment. The question is which one? The one in the hidden `.homestead` folder or the one in the place where I installed Homestead?

2.) When I go to `http://site1.local:8000/` in a browser I get a Site cannot be reached error - refused to connect. When i go to `http://localhost:8000/` I get 'No input file specified.'

3.) The command Homestead from the command line isn't recognized as a internal or external command - should it be? I read people with similar problems should run the command `homestead up` yet it isn't recognized for me.

Here is my Homestead.yml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/LaravelProjects/projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: site1.local
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Here is my host file:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost


#laravel project 1
192.168.10.10 site1.local
```

I have updated my hosts file. I have tried running `vagrant reload --provision` and `vagrant destroy` and other vagrant commands without luck. Any suggestions?

Here is the dump of running `vagrant reload --provision`

```
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 5.0.20
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.1
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/Users/Radley.Anaya/LaravelProjects/Homestead
    default: /home/vagrant/Code => C:/Users/Radley.Anaya/LaravelProjects/projects
==> default: Running provisioner: file...
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: C:/Users/RADLEY~1.ANA/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20160801-10000-y9i8nr.sh
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: script: Creating Site: site1.local
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: script: Restarting Nginx
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: script: Creating MySQL Database
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: script: Creating Postgres Database
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: script: Clear Variables
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: You are already using composer version 1.2.0 (stable channel).
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: C:/Users/RADLEY~1.ANA/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20160801-10000-i2qk4o.sh
```

***Update***

I ssh'd into the VM and my folder structure looks like: `Code/first/index.php` how do I update it?

My `Homestead.yml` file has a different directory structure - I think that is likely causing my issues. How do I fix this?

From my understanding the .yml file dictates the folder structure of the virtual machine? This isn't the case??

Comment: Can you paste your hosts file and the output of the "vagrant reload --provision". Can you make an nmap to the Vagrant IP "nmap 192.168.10.10" and paste the output?

Comment: @JesúsAmieiro How do I make an nmap to Vagrant IP?

Comment: You have to install nmap (the installations method depends of your host machine) https://nmap.org/download.html and then you have to execute "nmap 192.168.10.10". This command will show you the open ports of your Vagrant VM.

Comment: @JesúsAmieiro I think it is because my directory structure is weird on the homestead vm.

Comment: If you can ssh into the VM the problem is in the directory mapping. Check if the directory "~/LaravelProjects/projects/Larevel/pubilc" exists and then try to provision the VM machine (vagrant reload --provision). I have a manual in my blog with this information http://www.jesusamieiro.com/how-to-add-a-new-project-in-laravel-homestead/

Comment: @JesúsAmieiro I took a look at your blog and it helped me. This command `$ ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ -la` revealed that my site was enabled. I was able to view it finally after removing the port from the url. This works for me: `http://site1.local` but not `http://site1.local:8000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

My mappings were messed up. I ssh'd into the vm to verify and updated my .yaml file then provisioned the vm and everything is working. Also I had to remove the port from my url.

Comment: can you post the answer? :)